# Using in-build Visual Composer param types in custom param types

Tags: pages, color-picker, drag-drop

I'm developing a new param type by following [this guide](https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/display/VC/Create+New+Param+Type). This new param type will contain a color picker and 3 text fields.To use VC's in-built colorpicker, made a littre research and found these codes from `js_composer/include/params//colorpicker/colorpicker.php`

```
function vc_colorpicker_form_field( $settings, $value ) {
    return '<div class="color-group">'
           . '<input name="' . $settings['param_name'] . '" class="wpb_vc_param_value wpb-textinput ' . $settings['param_name'] . ' ' . $settings['type'] . '_field vc_color-control" type="text" value="' . $value . '"/>'
           . '</div>';
}
```

So copied codes from here to my custom param:

```
add_shortcode_param( 'my_param', array($this, 'my_param_settings_field') );
function my_param_settings_field( $settings, $value ) {
           return '<div class="color-group">'
           . '<input name="' . $settings['param_name'] . '" class="wpb_vc_param_value wpb-textinput ' . $settings['param_name'] . ' ' . $settings['type'] . '_field vc_color-control" type="text" value="' . $value . '"/>'
           . '</div>'
           . '<input ...>'
           . '<input ...>';
        }
```

But this is the result:

[image]

As you see there are 3 text fields, first one didn't become a color picker.

How can I use in-built VC param types (like **colorpicker**) in my custom param types?